# How a link to file is given after php extension? like register.php/reg_icon.png

Tags: php

how this kind of url to created in a server after the php extension..
https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/N38unEWRxJY.png ??

Answer (score 0):

Usually by placing a PHP file at `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/rsrc.php` and then typing the URL with a `/` and then some extra stuff.

`rsrc.php` is responsible for determining what to do with the data in the URL (which can be extracted from `$_SERVER`).

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is make an .htaccess rule, so that rewrites anything after 'rsrc.php' to $_GET e.g $_GET['load_file_relative_path']

Then I would make a script called 'rsrc.php', which then checks if the file path is valid, and if it is then output the contents (basic example).

```
<?php
   $base_path = "" // set a bath path to prepend to the relative path

   if(isset($_GET['load_file_relative_path']))
   {
      // Check if file exists (put additional security checks here)
      if(is_file($base_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_GET['load_file_relative_path']))
      {

         // Depending on your use, hard-code header or get the mime type from file
         header('Content-type: image/png');
         file_get_contents($base_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_GET['load_file_relative_path'])
         exit();

      }


   }

?>
```

Of course this is a security hole so you would need the nessesary checks in place so it will only load images from certain directories.